# Regular expression in python to replace last two digits of a column value where if last two digits are 30 then replace it with 50

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logic, python-re

I have the following data frame

```
abc=pd.DataFrame()

abc['Col_A']=[1900,1200,1230,1130,1300,0330]
abc

    Col_A
0   1900
1   1200
2   1230
3   1130
4   1300
5   0330
```

from the above data frame I want to replace last two digits wherever I see 30 I want to replace it with 50

My expected output is below.

```
    Col_A
0   1900
1   1200
2   1250
3   1150
4   1300
5   0350
```

If not re than anything other than Regular expression will also be helpful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this,

`df["Col_A"] = df["Col_A"].apply(lambda x: x+20 if x%100==30 else x)`

OR 

`df["Col_A"] = df["Col_A"].apply(lambda x: str(int(x)+20) if int(x)%100==30 else x)`

Comment: Those also work but are much slower than `np.where`. When I test with 6K rows, `np.where` takes ~390 µs and `apply` takes ~2.76 ms. At 60K rows, `np.where` takes ~1.18 ms and `apply` takes ~56.4 ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `Col_A` values are actually strings, then we can use `str.replace` here:

```py
df["Col_A"] = df["Col_A"].str.replace(r'30$', '50')
```

Note that values like `0330` will only retain their leading zeroes in the event that they are *strings*, and not integers, the latter which don't actually have any leading zeroes.

To cover the same logic with a numeric column, use:

```py
df["Col_A"] = np.where(df["Col_A"] % 100 == 30, df["Col_A"] + 20, df["Col_A"])
```

Comment: what if they are they are integer?

Comment: @Annu I have given you an option for doing this with numbers.  But note that there is no integer `0330` (it might actually be an octal literal instead).

Comment: numeric one is not working on 1130 value

Comment: @tdy Yes, that also works...but avoiding the cast to string and using the modulus would probably perform best, hence I used it.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen! yes @tdy I did that too converted to string then again back to int.